# Is the Ephemeris news website of good Latinity?

Tags: contemporary-latin

Is it a good idea to use the [Ephemeris](http://ephemeris.alcuinus.net/nuntius.php) news website to read articles in Latin and expand my vocabulary?

As an example, here is the latest article published:

> Praeclarus praeses Unionis Sovieticae Michael Gorbačev, annos iam XCI natus, diutino morbo affectus heri mortuus est. Ille Gorbačev notissimus est verbis suis "Glasnost", id est perspicuitas, atque "Perestroika", id est refectio, quibus Unionem Sovieticam, quam regebat, maxime reformavit: ipse praeterea Gorbačev non modo Russicorum libertatem auxit, sed armorum nuclearium potestas ut valde deminueretur maxime curavit, qui praemium illud Alfredo Nobel dicatum pro pacis propagatione obtinuerit. Hoc ast est quod eius Gorbačev maxime recordatur consilium: anno enim MCMXCI Unionis Sovieticae finem sanxit.

Comment: Not really a full answer, but my impression of that website has been that the Latinity, as far as I can judge, is usually so good that if something gives me pause, my default assumption is that they know something I don't. In your example, I find the last sentence a little irritating: Is *hoc ast est* really idiomatic? I would have written *At hoc est*. Also, passive *recordari* is attested, but quite unusual.

Comment: Thank you for your insight